# How to upload s3 using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to upload my logs to my bucket
I never been used python and boto3
This is my code

```
import os
import datetime as dt
import boto3

x = dt.datetime.now()
date = x.strftime("%Y%m%d")
bucket = 'mybucket'
dir_path = "/log"
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def log():
    global dir_path
    for (dir_path, dir, files) in os.walk(dir_path):
        for file in files:
            if date in file:
                file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, file)
                print file_path

file_name = (log())
key = (log())
res = s3.upoad_file(file_name, bucket, key)
```

and this is result

```
log1
log2
log3
log4
Traceback *most recent call last):
File "test2.py", line 21, in <module>
  res = s3.upload_file(file_name, bucket, key)
File "home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/s3/tranfer.py", line 273, in upload_file extra_args=ExtraArgs, callback=Callback)
File "home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/s3/tranfer.py", line 273, in upload_file raise ValueError('Filename must be a string')
ValueError: Filename must be a string
```

I have 4 log files

please help me
how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I'm not quite clear what you're trying to accomplish with the ```log()``` function.   You need to return the filename and ```print file_path``` doesn't do that.   You need to do a ```return file_path```.  That's what I think you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks it works, but Only one log uploaded.. I have 4 logs.. If I want to upload all then need to set one on one?

Comment: If your intention is to upload multiple files from the local computer, then you should put the `upload_file()` command _inside_ the `for` loop. That way, it will be called multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to upload more than one file, and you
stated that the `upload one log` works, you could
do the following, which basically goes through the
directory list as per your original intention, and
then for each file item that satisfies that criteria
(`date in file`), it returns the filepath to the
calling loop.

```
import os
import datetime as dt
import boto3

x = dt.datetime.now()
date = x.strftime("%Y%m%d")
bucket = 'mybucket'
dir_path = "/log"
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def log(in_path):
    for (dir_path, dir, files) in os.walk(in_path):
        for file in files:
            if date in file:
                yield os.path.join(dir_path, file)


for file_name in log(dir_path):
    res = s3.upload_file(file_name, bucket, file_name)
```

Please note that if you need to keep track of the results,
then you could make a change like so:

```
.
.
.

results = {}
for file_name in log(dir_path):
    results[file_name] = s3.upload_file(file_name, bucket, file_name)
```

Comment: That would be a new question.

Answer (score 0):

It was simple. this is my final code thanks.

```
import os
import datetime as dt
import boto3
import socket

x = dt.datetime.now()
date = x.strftime("%Y%m%d")
bucket = 'mybucket'
dir_path = "/log"
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def log(in_path):
    for (dir_path, dir, files) in os.walk(in_path):
        for file in files:
            if date in file:
                yield os.path.join(dir_path, file)


for file_name in log(dir_path):
    key = socket.gethostname() + '/' + file_name
    res = s3.upload_file(file_name, bucket, key)
```